# Fastlane failing tests on Jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, groovy, fastlane

Im trying to run fastlane scan on Jenkins, the tests execute well, pass, but on the last part it seems to fail because it can't access or start the simulator :

```
[32;1m   Executed 337 tests, with 0 failures (0 unexpected) in 5.657 (5.702) seconds
[0m
2018-12-19 11:09:41.006 xcodebuild[87795:568022] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 34.991 elapsed -- Testing started completed.
2018-12-19 11:09:41.006 xcodebuild[87795:568022] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 0.000 sec, +0.000 sec -- start
2018-12-19 11:09:41.007 xcodebuild[87795:568022] [MT] IDETestOperationsObserverDebug: 34.991 sec, +34.991 sec -- end
2018-12-19 11:09:41.007 xcodebuild[87795:568022] Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=6 "Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fa957d4a580 {Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Test runner exited before starting test execution." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test runner exited before starting test execution., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=If you believe this error represents a bug, please attach the log file at /Users/admin/.jenkins/workspace/app/jenkins_build/app/logs/App Development.test_result/3_Test/Diagnostics/App-C8F63971-F551-4B88-9B36-2CD1895231B9/Lassie-55B9D4CF-E286-4D7E-9C3D-2F9EF57C9E2B/Session-Lassie-2018-12-19_110906-AgsuGb.log}}}

Testing failed:
App Development.app (92694) encountered an error (Early unexpected exit, operation never finished bootstrapping - no restart will be attempted. (Underlying error: Test runner exited before starting test execution.))
** TEST FAILED **
```

The weird part is: if it try to run the same command in shell, it works just fine.
Already tried to restart and reset all simulators before starting the build, changed Always embed swift standard libraries to No, disabled parallel testing, but nothing works...

[EDIT]:
Added Xcode build log:

```
12:13:25.326 xcodebuild[4767:695436] <DVTiPhoneSimulator (0x7ff3b2a46860), iPhone 7, unknown class, 11.0.1 (15A8401), 5BDE8E89-5FC4-47FF-860A-EDBE34C64EED> got death notice for pid 9688, removing from SimulatorSessionMap
12:13:25.326 xcodebuild[4767:695436] <DVTiPhoneSimulator (0x7ff3b2a46860), iPhone 7, unknown class, 11.0.1 (15A8401), 5BDE8E89-5FC4-47FF-860A-EDBE34C64EED> claim LaunchSessionClaim_0x7ff3b50bab40 on simulator was relinquished
12:13:25.327 xcodebuild[4767:695436] <DVTiPhoneSimulator (0x7ff3b2a46860), iPhone 7, unknown class, 11.0.1 (15A8401), 5BDE8E89-5FC4-47FF-860A-EDBE34C64EED> claim LaunchSessionClaim_0x7ff3b50bab40 on simulator was relinquished
12:13:25.724 xcodebuild[4767:695436] <IDETestOperationCoordinator: 0x7ff3b5260130> finished receiving data from testing launch session
12:13:25.724 xcodebuild[4767:695436] <IDETestOperationCoordinator: 0x7ff3b5260130>: _considerFlushingDelegateBlockQueue - nothing to flush
12:13:32.328 xcodebuild[4767:695436] Test operation failure: Test runner exited before starting test execution.
12:13:32.328 xcodebuild[4767:695436] _finishWithError:Error Domain=IDETestOperationsObserverErrorDomain Code=5 "Test runner exited before starting test execution." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Test runner exited before starting test execution.}
```

[EDIT]More details here :

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/13956

Here is my jenkinsfile:

```
#!groovy
import groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic
import hudson.model.*

node() {
  echo env.BUILD_NUMBER
  env.PATH = "/Users/admin/.rvm/xgems/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1@global/bin:/Users/admin/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/admin/.rvm/bin"
  sh "source ~/.bash_profile"
  currentBuild.result = "SUCCESS"

    echo "+++branch: ${env.branch}"
    echo "+++upload: ${env.upload}"
    echo "+++commit: ${env.commit}"
    echo "+++lane: ${env.lane}"
    echo "+++ statusUrl: ${env.statusUrl}"
    echo "+++ commentUrl: ${env.commentUrl}"
    echo "+++ gitToken: ${env.GIT_TOKEN}"

   buildStarted()
   runUnitTests("", env.branch)
   buildFinal()
  }

  def runUnitTests(lane, branch) {
    bundleInstall()
    checkout(lane, branch)
    cleanEnvironment()
    cleanFolders()
    cocoapods()
    unitTests()
  }

  def bundleInstall() {
    sh 'bundle install'
  }

  def cleanEnvironment() {
    stage('Prepare environment') {
      prepareEnvironment()
    }
  }

  def unitTests() {
    stage('UnitTests') {
      sh 'fastlane ios unit_tests --verbose'
    }
  }

  def cocoapods() {
    stage('cocoapods') {
      sh 'fastlane install_intelligent_dependencies'
    }
  }

  def prepareEnvironment() {
      KEYCHAIN="/Users/admin/Library/Keychains/jenkins.keychain-db"
      sh "security -v list-keychains -s ${KEYCHAIN}"
      sh "security -v unlock-keychain -p tests ${KEYCHAIN}"
      sh "security set-keychain-settings -t 3600 -l ${KEYCHAIN}"
  }

  def cleanFolders() {
    stage('Clean folders') {
        sh "rm -rf /Users/admin/.jenkins/workspace/lassie/jenkins_build/"
        sh "rm -rf /Users/admin/.jenkins/workspace/lassie/output/"
        sh "rm -rf /Users/admin/.jenkins/workspace/lassie/DerivedData/"
    }
  }

  def checkout(lane, branch) {
    stage('Checkout') {
      def branchToCheckout = ""
      if (lane == "appstore") {
        branchToCheckout = "origin/master"
      } else {
        branchToCheckout = "origin/${branch}"
      }
      checkout([
              $class                           : 'GitSCM',
              branches                         : [[name: branchToCheckout]],
              doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
              extensions                       : [],
              submoduleCfg                     : [],
              userRemoteConfigs                : [
                      [credentialsId: '0000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000',
                       url          : 'https://github.com/doghero/lassie.git']
              ]
      ])
    }
  }

  def updateStatus(gitStatus, message) {
    sh "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' " +
            "-H 'Authorization: token ${env.GIT_TOKEN}' ${env.statusUrl} " +
            "-d '{\"state\": \"${gitStatus}\",\"target_url\": \"https://jenkinsurl.com/job/lassie\",\"description\": \"${message}\",\"context\": \"CI/Jenkins\"}'"
  }

  def commentGithub(message) {
      sh "curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' " +
              "-H 'Authorization: token ${env.GIT_TOKEN}' ${env.commentUrl} " +
              "-d '{\"body\": \"${message}\"}'"
  }

  def buildStarted() {
    updateStatus("pending", "InProgress...")
  }

  def buildSuccess() {
    updateStatus("success", "The build succeeded!")
  }

  def buildError() {
    updateStatus("failure", "Build failed")
  }

  def buildFinal() {
    echo currentBuild.result
    if (currentBuild.result == 'SUCCESS') {
        buildSuccess()
        commentGithub("Coverage: "+ getCoverage())
    } else {
        buildError()
    }
  }

  def getCoverage() {
    coverage = sh(
          script: "cat '/Users/admin/.jenkins/workspace/lassie/jenkins_build/code-coverage/report.json' | jq '.coverage'",
          returnStdout: true
          )
    return coverage
  }
```

Comment: What does the log mentioned in the error message of `xcodebuild` say?

Comment: @janpio just edited with the Xcode log.

Comment: Maybe it happens because fastlane close simulator for previous group of tests (which will take some time) and try start new tests on this "closing" simulator device? How many group of tests do you have? Can you share Fastfile with this tests configuration?

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean run the same command in shell? It may be some user issues, therefore best option is to set the working command as execute bash script in Jenkins to make sure you have the same setup.

Comment: @hris.to when I execute the same command using terminal, not by jenkins, it works.
there's not much difference between the two commands.
In Terminal : fastlane ios unit_tests --verbose
In Jenkins : sh 'fastlane ios unit_tests --verbose' --> Its executed by Jenkinsfile.
And in my Jenkinsfile, I first load the profile with : sh 'source ~/.bash_profile'

And change the env.PATH to get the correct ruby version.

Comment: Try to execute the command from within Jenkins -> Execute shell script. Also it may be useful to run `whoami` in both terminal and Jenkins. It may turn out your user is lacking some permissions.

Comment: @hris.to using the execute shell script produces the same error. And whoami shows that im Admin. Just a assumption, but can a crash can be occurring, but it is not visible when executing the tests?

Comment: You have some tests that are passing, and some that are not. Is there a chance that the tests that are passing are unit tests and the ones that are not running are UI tests? Are the passing/non-running tests in two different test targets?  I also see this from time to time: it works fine locally, but fails in Jenkins; I don't know the cause yet.

Comment: As I saw from your fastfile, you're also using CocoaPods with your project. We had a very similar issue which was a side effect of a Xcode 10 project created with an unsupported version of pods. We could fix it by installing the pre version of CocoaPods, which by now was already released. Does this issue persists after updating to a recent CocoaPods Version?

Comment: I had exactly the same problem and updating my pods `pod update` fixed it.